# Access AppHarbor environment variables from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angularjs, appharbor

I am using Sendgrid to send emails from an app hosted on AppHarbor with a .NET/AngularJS application. I want to be able to access the keys generated by the Sendgrid add-on from the AngularJS app. How can I do this?

Is it injected into the .NET app and passed along to the AngularJS part of the code, do I have to install some add-on module for it, or is there built in support for it that I have not yet found in the docs?